# Check which browsers are installed and then create a shortcut on their desktop

Tags: vb.net, browser

We can check installed browsers on the user's computer with the help of the given following code.

```
If File.Exists("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe") OrElse File.Exists("C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe") Then
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Chrome.exe")
End If

If File.Exists("C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe") OrElse File.Exists("C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe") Then
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Firefox.exe")
End If
```

After checking of any browsers that has already installed, how can we create a shortcut on desktop of any browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use simple code like this to achieve your goal. I have modified your code and provided a suitable solution. If you find it correct and convenient, please check as accepted solution.

```
     Dim path1 As String
    Dim path2 As String
    path1 = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
    path2 = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
    If System.IO.File.Exists(path1) OrElse System.IO.File.Exists(path2) Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Chrome.exe")
        Dim shell As WshShell = New WshShell()
        Dim shortcut As IWshShortcut = shell.CreateShortcut("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\chrome1.lnk")
        If System.IO.File.Exists(path1) OrElse System.IO.File.Exists(path2) Then
            shortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
            shortcut.Save()

        End If

    End If
```